# How do I save file to temp directory from file browser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsurl, temporary-files

I am using this method to open the file browser and search for an image file only.

```
NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray* imageTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openPanel setResolvesAliases:YES];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:imageTypes];
[openPanel setPrompt:@"Upload"];
[openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()]];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    [openPanel close];
```

When the 'Upload' button is clicked, the dialog box closes. How can I save the opened image to the temporary directory under a specific name?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `NSOpenPanel` class does not do any sort of file handling. In order to get the file that you user selected, you can use its `URLs` method, and then copy the file at that URL to the destination using `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. Here's an example of (un-tested) code:

```
NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray* imageTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openPanel setResolvesAliases:YES];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:imageTypes];
[openPanel setPrompt:@"Upload"];
[openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()]];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
   if (result != NSOKButton) {
       return;
   }

   NSString *myString = [[[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0] absoluteString];
   NSError *error = nil;
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:myString toPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:&error];
   if(error) {
       // Error! Tell the user by showing an NSAlert, etc.
   } 
}];
```

This is fairly straightforward and if you had searched on the net for "how to copy a file using Cocoa" then you would have found a plethora of answers. Same for how to access the files returned by `NSOpenPanel`.